# How do I remove alternating commas from an array in JavaScript, combining adjacent entries into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array such as:

```js
let arr = ["SO", "WHATS", "UP", "HELLO", "Cool", "Cat"];
```

How can I transform the array so that every other comma in the array is removed and adjacent items are combined, resulting in:

```js
let result = [ "SO WHATS", "UP HELLO", "Cool Cat" ];
```

Comment: Your `result` is not a valid array.

Comment: I guess you meant `["so whats","up hello","cool cat"]`? (otherwise it makes no sense). It's easy, show us what you've tried already and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: loop by two, push to a new array

Answer (score 3):

Given this expected result - `const result = [ "SO WHATS", "UP HELLO", "Cool Cat" ];`, you can create the new array using `Array.from()`, and then slice 2 items from the original array, and join them with a space:

```js
const arr = ["SO", "WHATS", "UP", "HELLO", "Cool", "Cat"]

const result = Array.from(
  { length: Math.ceil(arr.length / 2) },
  (_, i) => arr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2).join(' ')
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compact example that also accounts for trailing elements.

```js
const arr = ["SO", "WHATS", "UP", "HELLO", "Cool", "Cat", "!"];

function compactArr(array, count) {

  return array.reduce((a, e, i) => 
    (i%count ? a[a.length-1] += ` ${e}` : a = [...a, e], a), []);   

}

console.log('2: ', compactArr(arr, 2));
console.log('5: ', compactArr(arr, 5));
console.log('1: ', compactArr(arr, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to reduce every two items into one item:

```js
const result = [ "SO WHATS", "UP HELLO", "Cool Cat" ];
```

---

### Example

```js
const packItems = (arr, count) => {
  return arr.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    if (index % count === 0) {
      result.push([item]);
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1].push(item);
    }
    return result;
  }, []).map(item => item.join(' '));
};

console.log(packItems(["SO", "WHATS", "UP", "HELLO", "Cool", "Cat"], 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

Array elements are separated by commas, and cannot be removed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless

Comment: OP's question has been clarified so that the desired result is well-formed `[ "SO WHATS", "UP HELLO", "Cool Cat" ]`.